# Logic App - Easiest way to POST large message through HTTP

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App which is trying to POST a large message to an HTTP endpoint but I get error:

[image]

Is there any easy way to just increase the timeout? Or an easy way to POST large messages to an HTTP endpoint?

I'm aware about the default limit:

[image]

I've also tried Chunking but still the same issue.

Comment: Are you certain on what is causing the issue ? Is it the large payload or the target web service that is being called that is taking time. I see in the link that message size limit is 100 mb in a multi-tenant setup. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#http-limits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Maybe you can create an [Azure durable function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-create-first-csharp?pivots=code-editor-visualstudio) as your Http endpoint:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FrankDurableFunction
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            // Replace "hello" with the name of your Durable Activity Function.
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", "Tokyo"));
            //outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1_Hello", context.GetInput<ProcessRequest>()));

            return outputs;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1_Hello")]
        public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Saying hello to {name}.");
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            //ProcessRequest requestData = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<ProcessRequest>();
            // Function input comes from the request content.
            //string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Function1", requestData);

            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Function1", null);

            log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");
            var response = starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
            response.Headers.RetryAfter = new RetryConditionHeaderValue(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            return response;
        }
    }
    public class ProcessRequest
    {
        public string data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**2.** Turn on `Asynchronous Pattern` for `Http` settings

[image]

I did a test, and the result seems to be no problem.

[image]