Logic App POST bad request timeout logic app
Can't seem to find an example of proper set up. Trying to set up an HTTP POST in logic app, sending data to an external system. I can send small amounts of data but when I try to send more data in my body POST, I get badrequest server did not respond within the timeout limit. I tried setting settings of HTTP call to synchronous. This did not work. I tried chunking my data and doing a foreach http post to send in batches. That didn't work. It appears when I go over a certain number of items to send, this takes longer and everything times out. Not able to find a good solution to overcome this limitation.
Current issue: I am trying to send 500+ items to an endpoint. I do a for each loop, using chunked data, in groups of 100. Although, 50 seems to work better. In the foreach, a do an HTTP POST. For each group of data, an HTTP POST is performed of 100 items. If 300 items, no problem. If 500 items, I get a badrequest, http failed, server did not respond within timeout limit. My assumption was that communication was setup for each HTTP POST request. So if the first 100 sends and another HTTP POST is executed, why the timeout?
I have seen posts that say to use the do until but they give no indication of how that is set up. In my case, if I do a do until, do I send all of the data at once (500+) and hope it works? Do I chunk it? Is chunking doing anything? These are things I don't know and the documentation is pretty vague. Ultimately, what if I had to send 1K items or 10K items, is that possible with the right setup? This is what I'm trying to establish. Is it a setting in the http action? Is it a setting in the HTTP action plus something else? Anything I've found is vague at best and gives no working example.
I found this:
Logic App - Easiest way to POST large message through HTTP
similar issue but no resolution

The timeout duration for outbound HTTP requests in Consumption Logic Apps is 120 seconds:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=consumption#http-request-limits
You just need to keep that in mind and design your solution accordingly.
Update:
Regarding the Foreach loop: try setting it up to run sequentially:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops?tabs=consumption#for-each-run-sequentially

I'm familiar with this but it doesn't give me what I need. I need to know how to set it up. For example, do I do a do until loop? If so, how is that set up. Is the for each method the wrong approach? Things like that. What is the proper setup to send large batches of data. I'm familiar with the diagrams and all of that stuff on the MS side but no one seems to have actually set up a working example. More theory than anything else. But thanks for the response.

Everything depends on your requirements, dependencies, limitations, overall design - there's no "One size fits all" answer. You didn't clarify what exactly didn't work with the Foreach approach. In some cases it can be an adequate workaround. In other cases other Logic App limitations can be encountered, in which case considering switching to Azure Functions might make sense.

I updated my answer with an advice for the Foreach loop.

Webhook keeps coming up as a potential solution but no good documentation on how to use. So that might work just don't know how to use it

Did you try decreasing the Degree of Parallelism in the Concurrency Control as per the link from my answer? The fact that you're getting delays and timeouts when you go over a certain number of items to send in the Foreach loop, hints that it could be because the backend server cannot cope with multiple requests thrown at it at the same time, so decreasing the degree of parallelism might help here as the requests would be sent sequentially and not at the same time.

The link that you added to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66454149/ looks promising. I was the one who upvoted it 3 years ago :) though I didn't have a chance to try it. Having dealt with hundreds of Logic Apps with HTTP actions, most of the times there are no issues, other times other suitable workarounds could be found. But Azure Functions indeed are a good alternative when other options are exhausted and if the solution fits your design.
